# uniqueResult is deprecated in hibernate 5.2.2 ? how i can do?

Tags: spring, hibernate

hi，everyone i am a newcomer for hibernate. i write code with struts+spring+hibernate ,i encounter a trouble in this code

```
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import com.integration.entity.User;
public class UserDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDAO {
@Override
public User getUser(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String hsql="from User u where u.name='"+name+"'";
    User result=(User)((Query) this.getHibernateTemplate().find(hsql)).uniqueResult();
    return result;
}
```

the question is Query and uniqueResult() is deprecated ,how will i modify my code? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not only in your method. The hole class `HibernateDaoSupport`is deprecated as it said [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html)

I recommend you to configure your `SessionFactory` via Spring (as I see you use it) and use `createQuery` method to pass there your hql. Here is the example:

Configuring session factory:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:packagesToScan="-your-model-"
      p:hibernateProperties-ref="-your-properties-"
      p:dataSource-ref="-your-datasource-"/>
```

The DAO method:

```
private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

// Injecting session factory via constructor
@Autowired
public UserDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

String hql="from User u where u.name=:name";

public User getByUsername(String name) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery(hql, User.class)
            .setParameter("name", name)
            .uniqueResult();
}
```

Also your code us not secure. You should use params of query for preventing sql injections. I show it in my method. Read about session factory and injecting it in DAO.

Good luck.

---

**EDIT**

Also it's just an example. You can configure everything as you wish (via java code, not xml for example)